# Pandoc, input images and Word Export

Tags: latex, pandoc, cross-reference, pandoc-citeproc

I am required to convert a LaTeX file (`mypaper.tex`) to a DOCX file, for the requirement of a journal.

The latex document contains the following:

1. Tables, figures and equations
2. Bibliographic citations (my bibliographic database is titled `mycitation.bib`)

The figures are in a subdirectory called `images`. In the latex file, I have referred to this subdirectory by using the command

```
\graphicspath{{images/}}
```

I downloaded a CSL file from the Zotero database. Let us say that the name of the CSL file is `springer-science-reviews.csl`

Now I run the following command to convert from `.tex` to `.docx`

```
pandoc -s -S --filter pandoc-crossref --filter pandoc-citeproc --csl springer-science-reviews.csl --bibliography mycitation.bib mypaper.tex -o mypaper.docx
```

I see the following problems:

1. Cross referencing does not work. [\ref{tab:pollution} remains in the docx file as {tab:pollution}
2. Tables with commands like `@extracolsep` or those dependent on the latex's `array` package are not rendered correctly.

An example, which does not work, is given here:

```
\begin{table}[htbp] 
\centering    
\caption{Pollution data}    
\label{tab:pollution}  
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} clccccc}  
\toprule  & Name & V1 & V2 & Z1 & Z2 &Level\\  
& {} & {$\mu$g/m$^3$} &{$\mu$g/m$^3$} &{$\mu$g/m$^3$} &{} &{}\\ 
\midrule 
1 & MNEC & $77.160$ & $32.149$ & $3.793$ & $40.696$ &Good\\  
2 & BNEC & $142.643$ & $36.142$ & $8.801$ & $66.274$ &Moderate\\  
3 & TVCEN & $111.702$ & $41.657$ & $5.949$ & $57.070$ &Moderate\\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```